# What are IE classes?

Tags: class, internet-explorer, html5boilerplate

I see they are included in the HTML5 Boilerplate but I don't know what They are or why they may be useful. I searched on google but could not find any explanation to what they are
[search](https://www.google.com/search?q=IE%20CLASS&oq=IE%20CLASS&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2j0l2.1744j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're special classes to help you author conditional styles. For instance, `rgba` isn't supported in some older versions of Internet Explorer, so you may want to load a .png background image instead:

```css
article {
    background-image: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);
}

.oldIE article {
    background-image: url( 'faintRed.png' );
}
```

This is a contrived example, but it illustrates the intent behind these classes. Due to conditional comments around tags like `<html>`, you can conditionally place a class like `.oldIE` in the ancestral tree of elements, thus allowing you to create fallbacks for older versions of IE.

Conditional Comments no longer work in IE as of version 10. They're not longer needed given the parity of standards support found between Internet Explorer and other modern browsers.

These conditional classes were [removed from the HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/commit/13f17a737a7429bc102fe5f0991313f9f9162da7#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3b) in September of 2013.

Comment: Thanks! so can I achieve the same thing with modernizr?

Comment: @Danniiel Modernizr is a good approach as it draws attention to support for features, rather than trying to identify browsers.